# Error Message to React v15.5.* with React-Bootstrap v0.30.9

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I just recently update my react to version 15.5.* with React-bootstrap latest version v0.30.9, but I still receive this error message. I know this error raise because I have updated react to version 15.5.* but does anyone have the same issue? I don't believe is any of my code that causes the error but does anyone know when React-Bootstrap will fix the issue?

Error message:
[image: Error message]

Comment: i have the same problem. What version of react.js and react-bootstrap did you use before?

Comment: I have react v14.4 and react-bootstrap v0.30.8 before, and it works without any errors. The error arise when I update my react to v15.5 so I tried update my react-bootstrap to v0.30.9 to see if the error is gone but its still there. 

I am not sure if this update is in or not. 
https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/pull/2552